# ARM Parameter Passing

Tags: arm

I am trying to write an ARM program that takes three numbers and calculates the discriminant. It has two source files, driver.s & prog3.s. I understand how to find the discriminate, but how do I pass the values A, B, & C into the discrim function from the main function? I have included the code I typed thus far....

**MAIN() driver.s**

```
avalue  .reg    r0
bvalue  .req    r1
cvalue  .req    r2
final   .req    r3
loopcount   .req    r4

readA:
.ascii  “%d”
readB:
.ascii  “%d”
readC:  
.ascii  “%d”

addressReadA:   .word   readA
addressReadB:   .word   readB
addressReadC:   .word   readC

main:
ldr avalue, addressReadA    @ load in avalue
ldr bvalue, addressReadB    @ load in bvalue
ldr cvalue, addressReadC    @ load in cvalue
```

**DISCRIM() prog3.s**

```
avalue  .reg    r0
bvalue  .req    r1
cvalue  .req    r2
final   .req    r3

discrim:
mul bvalue, bvalue, bvalue      @ square bvalue
mul avalue, avalue, #4      @ multiply avalue by 4
mul cvalue, avalue, cvalue      @ multiply avalue by cvalue
add final, bvalue, cvalue       @ calculated discriminant
```

Comment: are you linking this for example with C or is this just a standalone asm program?  if standalone then you get to make up whatever passing rules you want.  If you are using a compiler then you need to conform to that compilers standard, and it is usually easy to make a simple function similar/same as what you are coding, compile and disassemble to see what registers you need to use.

Comment: This is a standalone ARM program. Thanks for the tips. Do you have any examples?

Comment: then it doesnt matter, you are interfacing with yourself, so you have a discussion with yourself to design the interface between functions.

Answer (score 1):

Going with the calling convention that C compilers use is not a bad idea, esp since if you go from pure assembly programs to C and asm mixed, you already have that experience.  And/or you may see the simplicity and wisdom in the calling conventions used.

How do you know what the calling convention for a compiler is?  1) read the manual/documentation and google.  2) just try it.  Prototype a function that is similar in the number of operands the type of operands and return value and feed it real-ish numbers and see what it produces.

Compiling to asm sometimes works but with pseudo instructions and other things done by the assembler I prefer to dissemble than to compile to asm YMMV.

```
unsigned int fun ( unsigned int a, unsigned int b, unsigned int c );
unsigned int test ( void )
{
    return(fun(1,2,3));
}
```

which with gnu currently results in

```
00000000 <test>:
   0:   e92d4010    push    {r4, lr}
   4:   e3a02003    mov r2, #3
   8:   e3a01002    mov r1, #2
   c:   e3a00001    mov r0, #1
  10:   ebfffffe    bl  0 <fun>
  14:   e8bd4010    pop {r4, lr}
  18:   e12fff1e    bx  lr
```

Each combination of compiler and target may have a different calling convention, there is no reason to assume that different compilers or versions of the same compiler use the same convention.  ARM, MIPS, and no doubt others try to help/encourage/suggest a calling convention to use and some compilers simply follow that, why not.

There are lots of exceptions to the rule in the convention, but for ARM for the first up to four registers worth of parameters, in this case for up to four signed or unsigned integers or up to four less than or equal to 32 bit quantities (float can create exceptions) the first four general purposes regisers are used r0 for the first parameter r1 for the second and so on.  And currently the standard keeps the stack aligned on 64 bit boundaries.

So we see that the first parameter is indeed placed in r0 the second in r1 and third in r2, obviously you dont have to arrange those three instructions in that order, doesnt matter.

because this function is calling another function it has to preserve its return value in lr so that goes on the stack, because the standard says to keep the stack aligned on 64 bit boundaries they are pushing another register on the stack r4 is arbitrary it could be any register, this is the one the tool chose.

because the standard says to return in r0, code that implements one of these functions.

```
    unsigned int fun ( unsigned int a, unsigned int b, unsigned int c )
    {
        return(a+b^c);
    }

00000000 <fun>:
   0:   e0800001    add r0, r0, r1
   4:   e0200002    eor r0, r0, r2
   8:   e12fff1e    bx  lr
```

it is very interesting now that I see this that the compiler did not do a tail optimization on the call, it could have not saved lr and did a branch to fun, since the return value in r0 is what test() was also returning in the same register.  really kind of baffled that that didnt happen.

but you can see that indeed the return value is left in r0, and per the convention we can trash r0-r3 we dont have to preserve them, and these functions are not.

if you change test to this

```
unsigned int fun ( unsigned int a, unsigned int b, unsigned int c );
unsigned int test ( void )
{
    return(fun(1,2,3)+7);
}
```

then it cant tail optimize and also shows the return register so you dont have to create a fun() function to see it.

```
00000000 <test>:
   0:   e92d4010    push    {r4, lr}
   4:   e3a02003    mov r2, #3
   8:   e3a01002    mov r1, #2
   c:   e3a00001    mov r0, #1
  10:   ebfffffe    bl  0 <fun>
  14:   e8bd4010    pop {r4, lr}
  18:   e2800007    add r0, r0, #7
  1c:   e12fff1e    bx  lr
```

you can do this kind of thing with other targets or other compilers, and there is no reason to assume that one target has the same convention as another.

```
Disassembly of section .text:

00000000 <fun>:
   0:   0f 5e           add r14,    r15 
   2:   0f ed           xor r13,    r15 
   4:   30 41           ret         

0000000000000000 <fun>:
   0:   8d 04 37                lea    (%rdi,%rsi,1),%eax
   3:   31 d0                   xor    %edx,%eax
   5:   c3                      retq
```

and this one is stack based instead of register based

```
Disassembly of section .text:

00000000 <_fun>:
   0:   1166            mov r5, -(sp)
   2:   1185            mov sp, r5
   4:   1d41 0004       mov 4(r5), r1
   8:   6d41 0006       add 6(r5), r1
   c:   1d40 0008       mov 10(r5), r0
  10:   7840            xor r1, r0
  12:   1585            mov (sp)+, r5
  14:   0087            rts pc
```

But if this is just a pure assembly project and you dont have to interface with compiled output, do whatever you want, part of designing the project is not just each individual function but how they interact, no different than C or Python or some other language you have to still define the interface for yourself between functions.  Assembly doesnt make that special or different, just another language.